# Angular2 Root component with body selector

Tags: angular

I have an app using angularjs, and i want to start rewriting this app to Angular2.
Original app is unfortunately mix of Asp.Net MVC when body was as as ng-app.

I want to do the similar approach in Angular2 to set AppComponent selector to body.
So then i will be able to take step by step rewriting old app to new components but.

My problem is that template is required inside of component. Is this possible to be without template since html will be printed from server?

Currently it works like that. When user hits page Server returns html

```
<html>
<body ng-app="flymark">

Here could be any angular directive or other controolers

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide an excerpt of how it's currently implemented?

Comment: @ElwinArens done. But i think its not possible because what i want to do compile component which does not have template and AOT is actually compiling templates

Answer (score 0):

This is possible If I understand correctly , It is not always the case that you have to use template inside component only it depends on your preference and needs :

You have two options to use template:

1. Template
2. TemplateURL :

   `templateUrl: 'https://test.html',

    styleUrls: ['https:/test.css']`

You may use template URL and pass your servers URL to the template URL this should work perfectly fine but you must do changes on your template even though it is in server so as to interact with your component or it wont respond the way you want it to ...

You should divide your html into several other components as per your needs providing the URL. This will enable you to target whatever portion of template you want.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Yes it wont if you pass it as single HTML file . Since there is no way to target body as selector. But you may divide your html files into seperate templates and then call it through different compoenents that way you can target body and have seperate selector for it. In any case you may need to make changes to your current template

Comment: Yes but read the original question :) It it what it is :( i cant rewrite whole app.

Comment: All i need is to have possiblity to bind root component to body, then inside i will insert right component.

Comment: <root><body></body></root> this should work and you can bind it all inside the root component but in any case you may need to do some tweaking to your html file you can call this via normal root selector

Comment: `<root><body></body></root>` won't work, the browser will try to fix the page and add a wrapper `body` tag around the `root`